# How to make background image take full width without cropping?

Tags: html, css, image

We have set an image as a background image using the following code below and place text on top of it. Is there a way to display the image as a background without the "cropping" regardless of the height of the content on top of the image?

A pattern that occurs is that as the content grows so does the height of the image. If the solution requires that we get rid of that, then I am okay with that.

Note: images will not always be the same size.

Current results 
[image: current]

Desired results
[image: desired]

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.banner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.banner__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner__content {
  padding: 200px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner__image" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/people-large-group-vector-id519533182')"></div>
  <div class="banner__content">
    <h1>Compellingly seize high-payoff supply chains</h1>
    <h2>Compellingly underwhelm extensive technology rather than low-risk high-yield manufactured products. Phosfluorescently brand just in.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a percentage value in `padding-bottom` value, the percentage is calculated from the `width` of the element, not from `height`, as one might think.

Which means

```
padding-bottom: 42.773%; /* (438 × 100 / 1024) */
```

... will always have a minimum height allowing it to display the uncropped image (which, in your case has `1024px` × `438px`).

```css
.min-ratio {
  padding-bottom: 42.7%;  /* (height × 100 / width) */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.banner__content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000065;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .banner__content {
    position: static;
  }
  .min-ratio {
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.banner__content>* {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-ratio" style="background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/people-large-group-vector-id519533182)">
  <div class="banner__content">
    <h1>Compellingly seize high-payoff supply chains</h1>
    <h2>Compellingly underwhelm extensive technology rather than low-risk high-yield manufactured products. Phosfluorescently brand just in.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you'll need to stop the image from repeating vertically, using `background-repeat:no-repeat` so that when the div gets too tall (on mobile, for example) it doesn't repeat the image.

The above technique allows you to set a minimal ratio on an element, without having to hard-code `width` or `height` values across different `@media` responsiveness intervals.

Since stack snippets looks down, here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/mek0chne/4/

Comment: I think the percentage value is a good start, but it has led to a larger than expect height for the `<div class="banner">`

Comment: That's because it probably has margins, paddings or borders, which are affecting the ratio. You want to place all those to a wrapper (parrent), so the element is left without and has correct aspect ratio. I'll update the example.

Comment: is the content supposed to be on the image? I cannot see it when clicking run code snippet.

Comment: @user, There was a problem with [SO] server. It was down. Returning `500` error (out of service). See the updated example on how to control `border` and `margin` of block-level elements without affecting their ratio.

Comment: Well, it looks like SO is still down. I've put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/mek0chne/

Comment: What do you mean by "content"?

Comment: There is not `<div class="banner__content">` element in the example. Is there a way to fix the height, but make the `width: 100%`? Still getting a large image. Do you think an image that is maybe 1680x480 would work better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169700/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-usernameabc).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an padding in .banner

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding : 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: This may be useful but depending on the amount of content and also on whether or not the user wants the text to appear at a different height it may not be the best solution. The solution youve given is a good start but using padding is not a resizeable solution, it can also offset other object like the text which may be intended to be positioned at/near the top.

Comment: @Remi.M After some trial and error, the fixed padding of 50px at the top and bottom still led to cropping on different breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this if you don't know what's the height of the image is going to be , you can use an image instead of a div with background and set its position to absolute : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfthy8kq/)

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.banner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.banner__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner__content {
  padding: 200px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

#bg{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <!--
  <div class="banner__image" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/people-large-group-vector-id519533182')"></div>
  -->
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/people-large-group-vector-id519533182" id="bg"/>
  <div class="banner__content">
    <h1>Compellingly seize high-payoff supply chains</h1>
    <h2>Compellingly underwhelm extensive technology rather than low-risk high-yield manufactured products. Phosfluorescently brand just in.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then do not use the image as a background image. Use it as an normal image.

```
<div class="banner__image">
    <img src="url of the image">
</div>
<div class="banner__content">
    <!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```

And for the CSS

```
.banner__image img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.banner__image{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner__content{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Now this should work

Comment: this results in an image that does not take up full width.

Comment: @usernameabc I have updated the answer. Check it once.

Comment: I had to add a `padding: 5%` to the `.banner__content` class, but otherwise this works for images that are not wide (< 640x480), but for images that are wide and large (>1855x1237) then it seems to provide a really large height to the element.

Comment: turns out this works once the images are sized properly.

Comment: @usernameabc I didn't get that. It's not working for which type of images? Also, if you want the pics to be full screen, then use height: 100vh; width: 100vw for .banner__image and the image inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the max and minimum height attributes in css for your class:

.banner

in addition you can also look at the background-repeat css attribute to prevent the image from repeating or alternatively to repeat on both or only on the x or y axis.

I can provide some code if you like but these are very self explanatory, there may be more elegant solutions but this will help you achieve what you're looking for.

Repeat:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Height:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Comment: @lm-Harrison By setting the min or max heights, it becomes difficult to manage the smaller breakpoints where we may not want the same height attributes.

Comment: @usernameabc Fair point, though that is generally what using different css classes manages. without setting a minimum height for the container though im afraid you would need to convert it from a background to an img, the problem is if you use a padding that it will always give a lot of extra space dependant on the amount of text.