# How can I make my header pic on my website responsive?

Tags: html, css

My header pic looks blurry when I resize the screen so how can I fix this? The height is 300px.

```css
.headerpic {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="headerpic" src="via.placeholder.com/1914x540 " alt="English header" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>English</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How large is your image? We don't have access to your `header.jpg`, so you need to add a placeholder image. You can use a placeholder service like https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500 - change the numbers to your image's width and height and use that in your `src` attribute.

Comment: its  blurry or not responsive?

Comment: you picture needs to be high quality pixelwise and larger then the screen in demnsion. Using a photo which with a width of 10 inch and opening it on a screen with 20 inch then the foto will look blurry even if it has more pixels. The reason is, that that it might have many pixels but a low quality of the pixels. In that case you need to max imit the photo can expend to.

Comment: It would be the best if we can see this picture and know its size - there are many possibilities - image quality, css bug, poor device user-agent, device settings "images only low quality" ...

Comment: for lineart such as logos etc, svg will always be sharper than a resized png or jpg.

Answer (score 0):

If your original image is proper and has the desired dimension, try the following code. Generally, banner images are provided as background. There are ways of using them using HTML, but I will provide you a simpler way of achieving the same result.

```
.header {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  /*Note - If the image doesn't appear, try correcting its path as per your project setup */
  background: center url('images/header.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-attachment: fixed; // not required */
}
```

```
<div class="header">
  <!-- <img class="headerpic" src="images/header.jpg" alt="English header"/> -->
  <div class="title">
    <h1>English</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, is there another way of doing this because I've got a lot of pages and I don't want to have to do this for every page because they have different header images?

Comment: @cherlloydfan Are images on those pages appearing properly or are those also blurry?

Comment: they are blurry as well

Comment: Then this needs to be done from CSS side. Using **position: absolute;** you can define a HTML image to look like a background image. Take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007304/how-to-make-background-image-take-full-width-without-cropping#50007506